# Is it possible to make my application as a default internet browser

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer

I am trying to develop a simple security tool for using internet browser. Is it possible that their only choice is to use my deployed application in desktop with the internet browser icon, because right now I just hide the software at my drive.

I am using a simple code like this:

```
Private Sub login(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click

    Dim Username As String = "user"
    Dim Password As String = "pass"

    If txtusername.Text = Username And txtpassword.Text = Password Then
        Process.Start("iexplore.exe")
        Environment.Exit(0)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid User Account!")
    End If
End Sub
```

I am doing this so that before they use the browser it will have a prompt account. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to have the browser locked down, so they have to go through your application first. What if they just download a different browser?

Comment: Yes, they cannot install or download a new browser because there is user type Admin and user only.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not ideal BUT for the sake of answering your question, here are the quick and very dirty steps:

1. Create a registry entry that will block your the iexplore.exe process from executing

Open up Notepad, paste the text below and save it out as disallow.reg then double-click on the file.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"DisallowRun"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun]
"1"="iexplore.exe"
```

2. Add some code that will read/change the value of the registry so you can allow IE to run again if the users are authenticated

   My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun","1", "")

...the rest of your code goes here

Likewise once the app closes, you set the value 'iexplore.exe' back

```
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun","1", "iexplore.exe")
```